# How to make return the result of (need to bind image to view) webapi to getjson?

Tags: asp.net, image-processing, asp.net-web-api, asyncfileupload

I am working on webapi. I had optimized the images and saving in folder here. I had uploaded images into one folder before uploading in to the destination folder.

I am optimizing a single image in to 3 different sizes (large, thumbnail, medium) but image sizes are saved in one folder, now I need to make return those images to view page and bind to view page. How can I do that? I am new to webapi.

Here my controllers

```
  public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            var uploadFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Sprites/UploadFolder");
            uploadFolder = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff"));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);
            var streamProvider = new PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider(uploadFolder);

            return Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                foreach (var uploadedFile in Directory.GetFiles(uploadFolder))
                {
                    var thumbnail = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "thumb-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
                    var medium = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "medium-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
                    var large = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "large-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
                    ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, thumbnail, 80, 80);
                    ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, medium, 48, 48);
                    ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, large, 128, 128);
                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
            });
        }
    }
```

and my class file

```
public class ImageTools
    {
        public static void Resize(string original, string output, int width, int height)
        {
            using (var image = Image.FromFile(original))
            using (var thumbnail = new Bitmap(width, height))
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail))
            {
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

                graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

                ImageCodecInfo[] info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
                EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
                encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
                thumbnail.Save(output, info[1], encoderParameters);
            }
        }
    }
```

and class file for save

```
public class PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider : MultipartFileStreamProvider
        {
            public PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider(string rootPath)
                : base(rootPath)
            {
            }

            public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
            {
                return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
            }
        }
```

finally my layout page

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "Upload" }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="image" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
}
```

Here I had the images in folder now I need to save those images as well. I need bind those in my layout page how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

as of above question i have example sight that helps more follow and look for as above question to implement the coding for your implement

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/379980/Fancy-ASP-NET-MVC-Image-Uploader?msg=4389108#xx4389108xx

Answer (score 0):

as of above question no problem i think it is increasing with quality option you just have to do simple just decrease the quality make upload image and check it once

```
 public static void Resize(string original, string output, int width, int height)
        {
            using (var image = Image.FromFile(original))
            using (var thumbnail = new Bitmap(width, height))
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail))
            {
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

                graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

                ImageCodecInfo[] info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
                EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
                encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 80L);
                thumbnail.Save(output, info[1], encoderParameters);
            }
        }
```